# Python convert integer to date

Tags: python, datetime

I have this list of integers and need to convert it to date using `python`.

- 42222  should be 8/6/2015
- 42290  should be 10/13/2015
- 42319  should be 11/11/2015

I get the equal date of the integer when `i paste in to excel then format the cell to Date`.

Comment: what is 42222 ??? is it cell address ?

Comment: How is `42222` equal to `8/6/2015` ?

Comment: why downvotes, now i cant ask another question.. @J.F Sebastian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel dates start counting around the year 1900. This will do it:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def xldate_to_datetime(xldate):
   tempDate = datetime(1900, 1, 1)
   deltaDays =timedelta(days=int(xldate)-2)
   TheTime = (tempDate + deltaDays )
   return TheTime.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")

>>> xldate_to_datetime(42290)
'10/13/2015'
```

Comment: Thank you it saves me :)

Comment: @Kyrie: this answer is wrong if `xldate` is less than 60. See the answer in the linked question.